# Understanding of inheritance in Java

Tags: java, inheritance

Please don't be angry if my question is stupid )

I have a piece of code:

```
public class LinkageTest { 

public static class Parent { 

    public void test() { 
        System.out.println("parent::test"); 
    } 
} 

public static class Child extends Parent { 

    public void test() { 
        System.out.println("child::test"); 
    } 
} 

public static class Tester { 

    public void test(Parent obj) { 
        System.out.println("Testing parent..."); 
        obj.test(); 
    } 

    public void test(Child obj) { 
        System.out.println("Testing child..."); 
        obj.test(); 
    } 
} 

public static void main(String[] args) { 
    Parent obj = new Child(); 
    Tester t = new Tester(); 
    t.test(obj); 
}
```

}

When I'm running it, the next string is printed:

`Testing parent... child::test`

I can't understand why `test` method with `Parent` is called if we have instance of `Child`? Can some one help me with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) The class `Child` redefines (overriding) the `test` method. (polymorphism)

2) In the `Tester` class, the `test(Parent obj)` and `test(Child obj)` methoda are overloaded. When you call the method, the method with the appropriate type is selected.

3) at the time `t.test(obj)`, the variable `obj` has an explicitly defined `Parent` type, so the appropriate method will be selected and "Testing parent ..." printed.

4) at the time `obj.test()`, the test method of the `Child` class will be called, since this is a polymorphism

Answer (score 1):

You are creating an object of **Child** via **Parent**  reference like

```
Parent obj = new Child(); // obj has Child and Parent both type
System.out.println(obj instanceof Parent); // it returns true
```

And Child overriding test mathod of Parent,

```
public static class Child extends Parent{ 
    public void test(){ //overriding here
        System.out.println("child::test"); 
    } 
}
```

while you calling **t.test(obj)** method

```
    public static void main(String[] args){ 
    Parent obj = new Child();
    Tester t = new Tester();
    t.test(obj); // obj created by Parent reference  
}
```

So catches by :

```
public void test(Parent obj){ // catches here
        System.out.println("Testing parent..."); // Here is your first output
        obj.test(); 
    }
```

then obj have **overridden test method** so it calls

```
public static class Child extends Parent{ 
    public void test(){ // overridden method first priority
        System.out.println("child::test"); // Here is your second output
    } 
}
```

if you change Child class test method name then it calls Parent class test method,and output will be

```
Testing parent...
parent::test
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you call

```
Parent obj = new Child();
t.test(obj); //object created by Parent reference
```

This obj is from **parent**, so it will call the "Testing parent" from Tester class.

Then, thanks of **polymorphism**, it will also call "child::test" from Child class because is overridden.

Try to call:

```
Child obj = new Child();
t.test(obj);
```

And you will see:

```
"Testing child..."
"child::test"
```

You should also put @Override on the test() method of the Child class.

Answer (score 0):

Thats because you're calling tester method with argument type of Parent. But the actual object inside, concrete implementation is Child. These might not be good words to describe it, hope you understand.

If you've called typeof(obj), it would return Parent. If you've debugged the app, you'd see that the method called is the one with Parent argument, because you pass argument which type is Parent.

The more concrete object is Child (actually you can cast the obj Child and it will work fine, because it is child on the inside). And when you do obj.test(), it will call method from child, because it is overriden by child.

Answer (score 0):

Decision to call `Tester.test(Parent obj)` is made at **compilation time**. During compilation compiler must pick method signature (not implementation, but signature). Compiler sees two methods with same name, but different signatures, it can pick only `Parent` signature because you've declared `Parent obj`. This is why in final byte code it will be presented like

```
find method test(Parent) in object t and execute it
```

Decision to call `Child.test` is made at **run time**. During compilation compiler finds only one signature for method test (despite two different implementations in Parent/Child, signature is the same). So actual implementation in both methods in **Tester** class will be:

```
find method test() in object obj and execute it
```

So, despite the fact that Tester.test(Parent) method is called, it still will try to find method test in passed object, as soon as you passed child - child's version will be actually executed.